# Trying to understand the Identity Theorem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, soft-question

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

It seems pretty amazing to me that two functions that agree on any single subset of the domain that contains an accumulation point must agree on the whole domain.

What is it about being a holomorphic function makes its global behavior so fiercly dependent on its local behavior?

Comment: Have you read a proof of the theorem? It should tell you _exactly_ what it is about holomorphic (specifically analytic) functions that makes it true.

Comment: Power series. (As you see if you look at the proof...)

Comment: Yes, it is amazing. And some people would (fairly reasonably) say that this feature shows the weakness of any human model of things that seems to say that natural phenomena behave this way. :)

Comment: welcome to the analytic world!!!